# How to handle doctrine2 data fixtures (flat file)

Tags: php, zend-framework, fixtures, doctrine-orm

I am looking at doctrine2 and how to handle data fixtures. I am especially interested in reading them from flat files (csv, yaml, xls).

In doctrine 1.2 data fixtures are handled like this: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/data-fixtures/en#data-fixtures

Any suggestion how to handle this in doctrine2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned by Steven the fixture-feature comes as a separate repo.
It took me some time to figure out how to install the data fixtures feature in Symfony2, so here is how I did it:

**add sources to your deps file:**

```
[doctrine-fixtures]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git

[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
```

**update your vendors**

```
$ php bin/vendors install
```

**register in in autoload.php:**

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    //...
   'Doctrine\\Common\\DataFixtures' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-fixtures/lib',
   'Doctrine\\Common' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-common/lib',
    //..
));
```

**add class which subclasses FixtureInterface:**

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
/**
 * 
 * setup of initial data for the unit- and functional tests
 * @author stephan
 */
class LoadTestingData implements FixtureInterface{
    /**
     *
     * @param EntityManager $manager 
     */
    public function load($manager) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setUsername("testuser");

        $manager->persist($user);
    }
//...
```

**load data fixtures via console command**

```
./app/console doctrine:data:load
```

Comment: Thats not enough to have a doctrine:data:load task though, you also need Symfony's DoctrineFixturesBundle, as mentioned here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Comment: How does this answer the question where the data is to read from a flat file ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a git submodule for that in the official doctrine git repo https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures

I am currently using it and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I use class-based fixtures, much better this way because you can handle associations and dependencies easily with the EntityManager directly, also easy for using in unit tests.

Here is the [library I use](https://github.com/cobbweb/Cob-ZendFramework-Doctrine2/tree/master/lib/Cob/ORM/Fixture) with Zend Framework modules, but you can just write your own loader. There is a [command line script](https://github.com/cobbweb/Cob-ZendFramework-Doctrine2/blob/master/bin/loadFixtures.php) too.